# Gradle with Docker Plugin (Palantir)

Tags: docker, gradle

I am new to Gradle and I have a problem with the palantir docker plugin.

I need to tag different docker images (with different jvm options) based on a gradle property.

In my build.gradle I have this:

```
afterEvaluate {
  if (project.enableRemoteDebugger) {
    docker {
      ..
      tags "${project.version}-debug"
      ..
    }
  } else {
    docker {
      ..
      tags project.version, latest
      ..
    }
  }
}
```

but, with this the tasks dockerTag and dockerPush disappear.

Any solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely your use of `afterEvaluate`. This shouldn't be necessary unless you are doing something really weird to set up `enableRemoteDebugger`.

Comment: I have  a multi-project build. The enableRemoteDebugger property is added in all the build.gradle of the subprojects while the afterEvaluate block is in the root. Without the afterEvaluate, the property is not evaluated correctly.

Comment: Ah OK. In that case, try putting the `if` statement inside the `docker {}` block, as this closure shouldn't be evaluated until the root build scripts from each project have been read (and `enableRemoteDebugger` has been set up). _Then_ you should be able to remove the `afterEvaluate`.

Comment: The problem you're having is that the plugin probably creates tasks based on the value of some variable(s) that you're setting up inside the `afterEvaluate` block, but the code in the plugin that creates those tasks is being run _before_ `afterEvaluate` is called (i.e. during evaluation).

Comment: Putting the if statement inside docker block not work. The property is not set. I think that the plugin use 'tags' before because the tasks are named dockerTag<tag>, ex: dockerTagLatest.